# How to create multiple User types with Devise Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, model

I have followed a few tutorials and starting to understand the syntax.

I am trying to build a real world working application - a marketplace (like an AirBnB).

- Users type 1 can sign up and list their booking available for rent.
- User type 2 can add the details of their item they are booking in
- Visitors can browse available bookings for rent.
- Admin - superuser access

Should I create 2 user models (seller_user, buyer_user)? of have 1 User model and define roles differently using CanCan or similar?

Whats the best rails way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to make the User class be used only for login and the user would belong to a Renter or Tenant via a polymorphic association, as in:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :identifiable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

If you don't know what polymorphic associations are, [you should read this tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

This code would be used like this:

```
subscriber = Tenant.find(1)
user = User.new
user.identifiable = tenant
user.save
```

So, your Tenant or Renter is going to be related to one user, the :identifiable field is a relationship (a polymorphic relationship) to another object.

With this a user could use this identifiable association to be a Tenant or a Renter and your SessionsController would be reused for both of them (and all the authentication logic too, since it would live inside of User and not these other classes).

Answer (score 0):

Add a `roles` column to `User` table.

`rails g migration AddRoleToUsers role:string`

Then use `Cancancan` gem. 
https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

Read `cancancan` readme.

You can set what access Users have with the `ability.rb`

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

The above shows that a user.admin? can view the full crud of any model. If you're not admin you can only read any model.

You might want to use `active_admin` gem to control the app on the backend.

Have fun!